# Metric on tangent vectors to tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $p$ be a point of $M$.

Let $v$, $v'$ be  tangent vectors to $M$ at $p$. Of course we have $\langle v,v'\rangle_p$ defined.

Let $u$, $w$ be tangent vectors to $T_p(M)$ at $v$.

How is $\langle u,w\rangle_v$ defined? How is it related to the metric of $M$?

Comment: what do you mean for $u,w$  tangent to $T_pM$??

Comment: $T_p(M)$ is a vector space and a manifold . v is a point of this new manifold so we can have tangent vectors to this manifold at point v, just like v is a tangent vector to M at point p.

Comment: ok.. if we name it $TM=\bigcup_p(T_pM)$, is this the manifold that you are talking??

Comment: i ask this, because $T_pM$ only is a vector space

Comment: I think this may related to the exponential map. We can get Guass Lemma. This is from the book "Riemannian Geometry" of Do Carmo.

Comment: isn't this [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_tangent_bundle]??

Comment: thanks for all your feedback.

Comment: $u,w\in T_{(v,p)}TM=(v,T_pM)$, right??

Comment: Each tangent space is a manifold. $T_p(M)$ is therefore a manifold. I am not talking about tangent bundle here. Just a single tangent space at p. i guess you are right, if i understand your notation correctly

Comment: when you say $u\in T_pM$ then $(u,p)\in TM$. Then as Igor said the natural choice to do is $\langle u,w\rangle _v=\langle u,w\rangle_p$ when $u,v$ are tangent at $p$... but if they are $u\in T_pM$ and $w\in T_qM$ for two different position $p$ and $q$??? :D greets!!

Comment: $u \in T_v(T_p M)$. u is tangent at v, not at p.  w is also tangent at v, not at p or q.

Comment: let me draw your attention to [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52509/riemannian-metric-of-the-tangent-bundle/635357#635357 ] I mistook posting here.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, $T_p(M)$ is a vector space, and the tangent vectors to $v$ are just $u+v$ and $w+v.$ The natural scalar product on the tangent space is therefore one inherited from $T_p(M)$ (if you think of $T_p(M)$ as "a vector space and a Riemannian manifold") which is thus exactly the one given by the Riemannian metric on $M$ at $p.$

Comment: Then $<u,w>_v=<u,w>_p$, where $u, w$ are viewed as tangent vectors to M as well as to $T_p(M)$?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: thanks so much for confirming