# Connection with the second tangent bundle as a doamin

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

The most minimal definition of the covariant derivative (or connection) I encountered, i.e. taking at least as possible field information in a neighbourhood, is a map $\nabla: TM \times \Gamma(TM) \to TM$, with $\pi(\nabla_\eta F) = \pi(\eta)$, and other properties (additivity, ...). And of course only the values of $Y$ along a curve $\gamma:I \to M$, with $\gamma'(0) = \eta$, is needed to evaluate $\nabla_\eta F$.

Because of the [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52509/riemannian-metric-of-the-tangent-bundle), where it says that the map $T_{p,v}TM\ni V\mapsto (d\pi(V),\frac{D}{dt}v(0))\in T_pM \oplus T_pM$ is independent of the curve, it seems to me that one can define a connection of only a single variable, namely $\nabla': TTM \to TM$ with the formula for $\frac{D}{dt} Z \equiv \nabla _t Z$, where $Z \in \mathfrak{X}(\gamma)$ is vector field along $\gamma$, by the following way.

Let $\bar{\pi}:TTM \to TM$ and $\pi:TM \to M$ be the natural projections and
$$
Y = Y^i \partial_{q^i}|_{\bar{\pi}(Y)} + \dot{Y}^i \partial_{\dot{q}^i}|_{\bar{\pi}(Y)} \in TTM
$$
with base point $\bar{\pi}(Y)=X_p \in TM$. In coordinates $\Phi \equiv (x \circ \pi \circ \bar{\pi}, dx \circ \bar{\pi}, dq, d\dot{q})$ where $dx = (dx^1,\dots,dx^m), dq = (dq^1,\dots,dq^m)$ and $d\dot{q}= (d\dot{q}^1,\dots,d\dot{q}^m)$ of $TTM$ the vector $Y$ reads
$$
\Phi (Y) = (p^1,\dots,p^m,X^1,\dots,X^m,Y^1,\dots,Y^m,\dot{Y}^1,\dots,\dot{Y}^m).
$$
Then, Define
$$
\nabla'Y := 
\left( 
\dot{Y}^k + X^i Y^j (\Gamma_{ij}^k \circ \pi \circ \bar{\pi} )(Y) 
\right) \partial_{x^k}|_p
$$
Where

- the components $X^i$ play the role of the value of $Z \in \mathfrak{X}(\gamma)$
- the components $Y^i$ play the role of the velocity $\eta$ (of the base point $p$)
- the components $\dot{Y}^i$ play the role of time derivatives of the componnts of $Z$, namely $(Z^i)'$

in the formula
$$
\frac{D}{dt} Z :=
\left( 
(Z^k)' + \eta^i Z^j (\Gamma_{ij}^k \circ \gamma) 
\right) \partial_{x^k}|\circ\gamma
$$

My question is whether this viewpoint correct and whether this map $\nabla'$ is well-defined ?